# image conversion from .pdf to .jpg not showing complete image

Tags: php, imagemagick

I am using imagemagick on a pdf file on my server, the conversion works correctly however when I look at the jpb that was converted only shows some of the items in the first page of the pdf.  However it is missing the complete image in the back.

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -size 250x350 testimage.pdf[0] testimage.jpg
```

this is my php code I am using to convert the pdf to jpg.

This is what it should look like [image: Correct image]

However it looks like this [image]

Comment: imagemagick doesn't do the conversion on pdfs, it simply calls out to Ghostscript. Gs isn't infallible, e.specially on older versions when it comes to CMYK pdfs

Comment: Any Ideas for solutions?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a layer try:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert testimage.pdf[0] -flatten testimage.jpg
```

Why did you have the  -size 250x350 in the code?